# alexcheuk Radial menu with nested sub menus

Tags: javascript, css, html, contextmenu, radial

I came across radial menu example provided by Alex Cheuk.

http://www.alexcheuk.com/hovermenu/

I am trying to make it contain any number of menu items needed, and with needed depth of nested menus.

I am able to get as many items needed in menu, but stuck in trying to make it nested.

Please give some tips that I should consider to make it nested.

Thanks

Comment: Explain what you mean by nested. How are you expecting that to work?

Comment: when I swipe to one menu item, i want to display other items that are like subcategories of the parent item.
I have done this work till now
http://ajitsonlion.com/work/secondWay/
but Alex Cheuk implementation fits better, and want to make it work with sub menus.
sorry for incomplete question, its my first question ever on stackoverflow.